# Python Converting LIST in to Dictionary with Array(list)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

i'm new here so sorry if this question was already asked but i could not find it.
I have 1 list and 1 arrray that look something like this.

```
['x1 y1','x1 y2','x1 y3','x1 y4','x2 b1','x2 b2','x2 b3','x2 b4']
```

I need to convert this list in to dictionary with a nested list like this

```
{x1:[y1,y2,y3,y4], x2:[b1,b2,b3,b4]}
```

something similar to this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d = ['x1 y1','x1 y2','x1 y3','x1 y4','x2 b1','x2 b2','x2 b3','x2 b4']
new_d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(map(str.split, d), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_result = {a:[d for _, d in b] for a, b in new_d}
```

Output:

```
{'x1': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], 'x2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
list_1 = ['x1 y1','x1 y2','x1 y3','x1 y4','x2 b1','x2  b2','x2 b3','x2 b4']
x1 = []
x2 = []
dict_1 = {}

for i in list_1:
    if 'x1' in i:
         j = i.split()
         x1.append(j[1])

    if 'x2' in i:
         j = i.split()
         x2.append(j[1])

dict_1 = {'x1':  x1, 'x2': x2}

print(dict_1)
```

Output:

```
{'x1': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], 'x2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']}
```

We create empty lists for everything that belongs to x1 and x2. We also create and empty dict that we will add values to later. WE then run a for loop that states that if a value has x1 within it, we will split the value and index one will be appended to x1. If 'x2' is in the value then index one will be appended to x2. We then create add values to the dictionary with x1 or x2 being the keys, and the list that corresponds with either x1 or x2 being the value. The output is what you are seeking.

Also of note, are you using numpy? Or are you are Java developer? In Python what you are looking for as output is technically a "nested list" with a dictionary being the main data structure. Not an array. In java, this would be an array within a map. I was just curious because you sound like a Java developer which I find interesting because which language you primarily write in can impact verbiage I guess.